Electron-builder tries to download old blockmap from latest pipeline
I am trying t configure Electron-builder autoUpdater to work with gitlab. The autoUpdater detects a new version (1.1.0 --> 1.1.1). Afterwards, it tries to download the blockmap from 1.1.0 from the latest pipeline's artifacts, but these artifacts only include the blockmap for 1.1.1. How do I solve this issue?
Logs:
[2024-07-12 14:15:10.676] [info]  Checking for update
[2024-07-12 14:15:10.713] [info]  Generated new staging user ID: 009e40b1-d81c-5a44-a6cc-43717bc4a1c2
[2024-07-12 14:15:11.298] [info]  Found version 1.1.1 (url: MindSpeaker-1.1.1.exe)
[2024-07-12 14:15:11.299] [info]  Downloading update from MindSpeaker-1.1.1.exe
[2024-07-12 14:15:11.300] [debug] updater cache dir: C:\Users\conta\AppData\Local\mindspeaker-updater
[2024-07-12 14:15:11.302] [warn]  disableWebInstaller is set to false, you should set it to true if you do not plan on using a web installer. This will default to true in a future version.
[2024-07-12 14:15:11.303] [info]  Download block maps (old: "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/59763170/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/release/build/MindSpeaker-1.1.0.exe.blockmap?job=build", new: https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/59763170/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/release/build/MindSpeaker-1.1.1.exe.blockmap?job=build)
[2024-07-12 14:15:11.771] [error] Cannot download differentially, fallback to full download: Error: Cannot download "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/59763170/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/release/build/MindSpeaker-1.1.0.exe.blockmap?job=build", status 404: 
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\MindSpeaker\resources\app.asar\dist\main\webpack:\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:204:34)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:49930)
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (node:events:513:28)


I tried looking if I had configured to look for the 1.1.0 blockmap somewhere, but couldn't find anything. The log file also says correctly that 1.1.0 is the old one and 1.1.1 is the new one. So why does it try to download it from the latest pipeline?
